Maintaining airplane mode after alarm powers on phone and rings on lock screen (in airplane mode)
I am running Android 12 on a Realme 8 5G phone.
This phone comes with the following clock application, which is separate from the Google clock application that can be downloaded from the Google Play store, which is similar, but seems to lack this feature. I am not sure about other clock applications. The application looks like this when opened:

This application has the feature that when you set an alarm for a time when the phone is off, the phone powers on and the alarm rings.
As far as I could tell, when the phone boots up and the alarm rings, the lock screen is on. This means, that as a special feature, wifi and data network from the notification drawer are not enabled (until the user logs in). This effectively enforces airplane mode. As such, this feature should be safe as far as phones going off while the phone is on a plane and turned off should go (because when it boots, the equivalent of airplane mode is in effect).
I am not an expert, but as far as I know airplane mode just temporarily turns out wifi and data network. If it does turn any other feature, this should be taken care of here.
I wonder whether it would be possible to select a "maintain airplane mode after unlock" as a feature on the lock screen.
This would mean, that, if, for example, a user is on a plane and the phone is turned off because it was turned off when they went on, and then the phone turns on after flight (for example to remind the user to take a medication or anything), then the user can also unlock the phone to take a note or do anything else while maintaining airplane mode.
This would be a feature.
Thank you for your answers.

Powering a phone up at a certain time is a special feature that requires a vendor specific app (or a rooted phone). Therefore what you describe is a feature wish you have to address to Realme. Android Stackexchange is a forum for Android users. The chance that someone responsible from Realme read your post is in my opinion very very low.
